# will installing ubuntu (dual boot) makes my pc boot slowly?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, system-call-fastboot

windows10 boots very fast ,as is known.But if I install a ubuntu to dual boot,will it slow down my computer's booting?
once I install ubuntu on win8.1,then it takes about 1min to boot,which is very annoying.
should I replace the "grub" with something else? and how to do it?

Comment: Windows 10 recovers hibernation (aka fastboot) very fast. It surely does not boot from a cold boot very fast. Try it on your own, disable the hibernation (fastboot) and then you'll see :)

Comment: Since you have to disable `fastboot` (UEFI) and `fast startup` (Windows) features to be able to boot into Ubuntu it is quite normal that your Windows OS will slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, installing Ubuntu next to Windows with the bootloader grub will *slightly* slow down your boot sequence, just by the mere fact that you have to select which system to start.

However, besides of this, the boot process should not be significantly slower on any of the installed systems. If a low number of seconds, depending on your reaction time or setup, is not crucial for you, this should not be a factor to take into consideration.

You can also configure grub, so that it takes less time to boot the highlighted option or change the default to your preferred system. For simplicity, I would advise to install the grub-customizer by entering the following in a terminal:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
>
> sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

In the general preferences, you can change the timeout to boot the selected system and you can also change the order of display for all entries, or remove them.

Be a little careful though not to delete all Ubuntu entries or with setting the timeout to 0, since that will result in grub not showing up. There are fixes for this, but it's avoidable.

As far as grub alternatives go: If boot time is your only concern, I highly doubt that any other bootloader will noticably increase your boot time against a customised grub.